# Converting decimal to int in SQL Server makes the result column nullable?

Tags: sql-server

I sometimes use [`sp_describe_first_result_set`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-describe-first-result-set-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) to generate type definitions from select queries, and today I noticed that casting a `decimal` to an `int` makes the resulting column nullable (at least according to the output of `sp_describe_first_result_set`). I'm interested because I couldn't find anything in the [convert docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) or the [decimal docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/decimal-and-numeric-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) about failing to convert decimals to ints other than overflow and truncation, and I'd expect an actual failure to raise an error and not just return null. But maybe I overlooked something?

Here's a simple reproducing case.

```
CREATE TABLE #test_case (
    dval DECIMAL(9, 0) NOT NULL
);

EXEC sp_describe_first_result_set N'
SELECT
    dval,
    CAST(dval AS INT) AS dval_cast
FROM #test_case;
', null, 0;

-- Output:
-- name       is_nullable  system_type_name
-- ----       -----------  ----------------
-- dval       0            decimal(9,0)
-- dval_cast  1            int
```

We're using Microsoft SQL Server Standard (64-bit) 14.0.3049.1

Comment: Just speculating here, but whether a column is nullable or not really only affects inserts. As this is essentially a computed column I imagine SQL Server is saying it doesn't know and therefore returning the highest common demoninator.

Comment: Heh, I thought I'd tested this out with different types but I hadn't; this is apparently _always_ true when converting, even from int to int. I noticed that wrapping with `ISNULL` will set it back to non-nullable, so I guess I just expected nullability to be threaded through. Thanks!

Comment: Even `CAST(1 AS int)` is nullable.